# Visual Studio 2013 Query results multi-line

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, query-designer

I'm connecting to a MySql database inside Visual Studio 2013.
I run a query and I have a grid with the query results. In the table, I have some fields with multiline  values. The grid result can't show this multiline fields.

EDIT:
I have a record that has a field with several lines and I want to see these lines in a Query Result Pane inside Visual Studio.

How can I change the Visual Studio configuration to allow multiline values in the query results pane?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean, "multiline values" ?  Is it a field with values separated by a comma, or multiple fields with each one a value for the same record (line) ? In both cases, that would inidcate that your database is not normalized. There could be several answers anyway, one of them could be to use a repeater inside your grid instead of the literals or similar controls you're using for other values.

Comment: I'm running the query inside visual studio environment. The "grid" is the query result pane of Visual Studio. Not a grid control in an app. I have a field that contains a string with several lines and I want to see all these lines.

Comment: Still I don't understand what you mean by "multiline values"...

Comment: A field that its value is a string with several lines separated by "\r\n"

Comment: Oh right, I understand now. And what is currently displayed ? Only the first line ? can't you just extend the row size to see the lines below ? Sorry I'm not of great help but I really didn't understand in the beginning what this was all about and thought I could help...

Comment: Yes, I ony see the first line